# Should MSE send reminders to users listing questions with no selected answer?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, notifications, unanswered-questions

Many, many questions have good answers, ignored or forgotten by the OP. A significant part of the issue comes from users unfamiliar with the site and the basics of accepting an answer.

**Could MSE send an email to each user with unaccepted answers?** The friendly email would contain links to eligible questions as well as simple instructions on selecting an answer.

This is a win for the OP as well as those who crafted answers.

This is in the vein of [“Welcome to MSE…”: Popup to remind new users to upvote and accept answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9923/welcome-to-mse-popup-to-remind-new-users-to-upvote-and-accept-answers).

Comment: yes it's a good idea but _only_ for newbies. Not for someone that is already familiar with the site, more than 2 months I'd say.